# url rewriting using htaccess for single files in html and javascript

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-parameters

my first question is "can i use html files for url parameter rewriting and handle the parameter in javascript?"

and the second question is:
what should i do?, if i want rewrite these urls:

```
*localhost OR sample.com*/blog.html
*localhost OR sample.com*/about.html
*localhost OR sample.com*/articles.html?title=sample-name-parameter
```

to these urls:

```
*localhost or sample.com*/blog/
*localhost or sample.com*/about/
*localhost or sample.com*/articles/sample-name-parameter
```

---

here's my htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex blog.html index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)$ /articles/$1.html?p=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't but you can do it by dividing current path, get current path with `window.location.pathname` use `split` to divide path in peaces.

```
var path = window.location.pathname, // "/article/something"
    peaces = path.split(),
    title = peaces[1]; // "something"
```

And try this htaccess code:

```
DirectoryIndex blog.html index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)$ /articles/articles.html?title=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: actually i tried it before, but it didn't work at all
apache server show this error: "The requested URL /articles/articles.html was not found on this server."

Comment: Then your article.html file in article folder is missing, simply remove `RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)$ /articles/articles.html?title=$1 [L]` line from htaccess code, If your file located in root